# How are CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR and CMAKE_BINARY_DIR set?

Tags: c++, cmake

When and how are these values set? Does it depend on the location of the CMakeLists.txt? Does it depend on where CMake is ran from?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.html

Comment: The docs don't make it super clear how these are set. It only specifies how they are set if you are running in -P mode. Which I am not. Looking at the --help with CMake I think I figured it out. But it would be nice if the docs you referenced had it. Or if there were stack overflow entries explaining it. That would have saved me some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example command where I configure a cmake project.

I'll be using the newer cmake style of doing things since it makes thing more clear.

```
# -S = CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR
# -B = CMAKE_BINARY_DIR
cmake -S C:\foobar -B C:\foobar\binary_dir
```

As you can see -S specifies the CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR, and -B specifies the CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.

The other ways to configure a build also follow this principle but I think the -S/-B really make things clear.

To summarize:

You are the one who sets the CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR and CMAKE_BINARY_DIR when you configure/generate the build.

EDIT:

If you need I can more in depth. So feel free to comment.